# Facebook API V3 - Create Facebook Page for Test User

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an application that uses Facebook login module.

I tried to get `manage_page` and `publish_page` permissions but Facebook is not giving these permission without review. So, I tried to create test user and gave him above permissions.

Then logged into Facebook with test user. Facebook is not letting test user to create facebook page.

I need to access user's pages but cannot do because I cannot create at the first place.

Comment: Groups and Pages are two completely different things. (Edited your question and title in that regard, since you seem to mean the latter.)

Comment: @CBroe yeah you are right, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the access_token of the test user and called facebook api with following json. And then I can see my test user had created page when I login to facebook.

/me/accounts

```
{
  "name": "Your Page Name",
  "category": 2211,
  "about": "Description",
  "picture": "your_page_picture_url",
  "cover_photo": {
    "url": "your_page_cover_photo_url"
  },
  "classic": 0,
  "city_id": 2505639
}
```